# Error during SonarQube Scanner execution with sonar python enabled

Tags: sonarqube

I am a very new sonarqube user, experimenting with my python project.

I have installed docker Sonarqube image which has Sonarpython plugin installed. I installed the linux base sonar scanner.

Using [these](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner) instructions, I configured the scanner.

However when running it, I run into:

```
11:28:33.486 INFO: Configured Java source version (sonar.java.source): none
11:28:33.496 INFO: JavaClasspath initialization
11:28:33.512 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
11:28:33.512 INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
11:28:33.512 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
11:28:33.513 INFO: Total time: 22.237s
11:28:33.670 INFO: Final Memory: 28M/509M
11:28:33.671 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
11:28:33.671 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
org.sonar.java.AnalysisException: Please provide compiled classes of your project with sonar.java.binaries property
    at org.sonar.java.JavaClasspath.init(JavaClasspath.java:66)
    at org.sonar.java.AbstractJavaClasspath.getElements(AbstractJavaClasspath.java:280)
    at org.sonar.java.SonarComponents.getJavaClasspath(SonarComponents.java:175)
    at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.<init>(JavaSquid.java:82)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSquidSensor.execute(JavaSquidSensor.java:91)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.AbstractSensorWrapper.analyse(AbstractSensorWrapper.java:48)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.execute(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:85)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.lambda$execute$1(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:59)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.withModuleStrategy(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:77)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.execute(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:59)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:82)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:136)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:122)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:359)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:354)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:317)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:136)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:122)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.doAfterStart(GlobalContainer.java:128)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:136)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:122)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecute(Batch.java:73)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:185)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:137)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:111)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:75)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
```

Do I need to configure `sonar.java.source` to successfully scan?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As soon as you are having some Java sources in your project, SonarQube is going to ask you for the compiled binaries as well in order to perform the analysis. It let you with 2 choices:

- If you want to focus on Python code only, then ignore java code by properly excluding it with the following scanner property: `sonar.exclusions=**/*.java`. For more information regarding exclusions, you can have a look at this page: [SonarQube 7.7 - Narrowing the focus](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/). Another way could be to only *include* python files, which would ignore all the other one. We however recommend to have the broader analysis possible.
- If you want to also analyse your Java code, then build your project first, and provide the path to your binaries and libraries (optional) using the following properties:   `sonar.java.binaries` and `sonar.java.libraries`. Refer to this documentation page for configuration: [Java Plugin and Bytecode](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Java+Plugin+and+Bytecode)

Comment: Thank you very much sir. That explains a lot. For my case, there was one file with java code.

Comment: Glad this helps. Can you please accept my answer then? Thanks!

Comment: Java Plugin and Bytecode this link not working in answer?