# Sonarqube failed during SonarQube Scanner execution

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarscanner

I just connected Jenkins to sonarqube but sonarqube fails with below logs and I have no idea what went wrong:

```
15:28:32.897 INFO: Sensor JavaSquidSensor [java]
15:28:33.123 INFO: Configured Java source version (sonar.java.source): none
15:28:33.132 INFO: JavaClasspath initialization
15:28:34.325 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
15:28:34.325 INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
15:28:34.325 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
15:28:34.326 INFO: Total time: 10.889s
15:28:34.384 INFO: Final Memory: 14M/360M
15:28:34.384 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
15:28:34.384 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
org.sonar.java.AnalysisException: Please provide compiled classes of your project with sonar.java.binaries property
    at org.sonar.java.JavaClasspath.init(JavaClasspath.java:64)
    at org.sonar.java.AbstractJavaClasspath.getElements(AbstractJavaClasspath.java:280)
    at org.sonar.java.SonarComponents.getJavaClasspath(SonarComponents.java:209)
    at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.<init>(JavaSquid.java:84)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSquidSensor.execute(JavaSquidSensor.java:87)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.AbstractSensorWrapper.analyse(AbstractSensorWrapper.java:48)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.execute(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:85)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.lambda$execute$1(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:59)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.withModuleStrategy(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:77)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.execute(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:59)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:82)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:136)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:122)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:387)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:383)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:346)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:136)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:122)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.doAfterStart(GlobalContainer.java:141)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:136)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:122)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecute(Batch.java:72)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:66)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:189)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:138)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:112)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:75)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Post Actions)
[Pipeline] echo
This will always run
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
```

I have to mention that this is a multi-component application written in different languages. Also both jenkins and sonarqube are running on the same machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily I found my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55684781/5553963

After adding `sonar.exclusions=**/*.java` to `sonar-scanner-cli/conf/sonar-scanner.properties` and running the pipeline again problem solved.

Comment: How about for JavaScript project?

Comment: For JavaScript or NodeJs project can use sonar.exclusions=**/*.js